# Running Flask App in Class with the ability to handle POST-requests

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to start a flask-app from a project using a new thread. Therefor I would like to have access to all attributes of this class-object from within the functions routed.

I minimal example looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

    class WebApp():
        def __init__(self, ip, port): 
            self.ip = ip
            self.port = port
            self.app = Flask(__name__)
            self.some_attribute = 'test'

        def some_function(self): 
            print('hello there')


        def run(self):            
            @self.app.route('/test/', Methods=['POST'])
            def test(self):
                #do something with the data recieved in the post request
                print request.json()

                #run some method
                self.some_function()

                return self.some_attribute

            t = Thread(target=self.app.run, args=(self.ip,self.port,False))
            t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    webapp = WebApp('localhost', 8000)
    webapp.run()
```

The problem with this example is, that "self" is not known in function test.

I already considered using Flasks flask.views.MethodView or flask.view.View, but it seems, that I would have to define for each route an entirely new class.

Is there any possibility I can do it like that?

**Update**: by removing the "self" from the signature from test() the "self" is accessible. Accessing the data from POST-request is still a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know its a bit late but, looking at your imports you forgot to import request:

```
from flask import request
```